# How to get my view to look like a schedule

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am working with MVC3 and entity framework

I have got a table with:

id - Day of the week - Muscle  - amount of sets - Customer

This is one table... It's just a simple little project.

But my problem is that I don't know how to get the proper View to get.

```
  **Monday    Tuesday    Wednesday   Thursday   Friday   Saturday   Sunday**
    Muscle    Muscle     etc...
    sets      sets
```

What I think I should do...first getting the list of the days the customer (which he created) wants to workout

Model

fitnessday is an property which is connected with my database with datacontext.

so like

```
   public class FitnessDay
  {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string dayoftheweek{ get; set; }
    public string muscle{ get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> sets{ get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> customerId{ get; set; }


     public virtual Customer Customers{ get; set; }
  }

  public class Customer 
   {
    public Customer()
    {
        this.fitnessDay = new HashSet<fitnessDay>();
    }

    // Primitive properties

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public string lastname{ get; set; }

    // Navigation properties

    public virtual ICollection<fitnessDay> fitnessDay { get; set; }

 }
```

-

```
    private IList<fitnessDay> trainingList= null;

          public IList<fitnessDay> Training() 
       {
           string nameOfCustomer= "bob";
           var Training1 = db.fitness.Where(c => c.Customer.name== nameOfCustomer); 

           trainingList= Training1.ToList();
           return trainingList;

       }
```

Controller

```
        public ViewResult TrainingView()
    {
        var list = model.training();

        return View(list); 
    }
```

view

```
   Don't know how to show it here.
```

Can someone help me out get the day of the week and place the proper Muscle and set underneath it (there could be several muscles per day)

edit: new information added

Comment: A [jQuery Calendar plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) would fit the bill nicely.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - That calendar is nifty!

Comment: It looks great. I will try, but I have never worked with jquery before. And It might complicate things even more.  edit: I looked at it, but my table is simple, it doesn't have timestamps - I just want the proper data below the Day of the week

Comment: You should be able to use a simple HTML table to do this. But I would need to see the definition of fitnessDag to give you a specific example. Please add that to your question.

Comment: @KevinJunghans I added it like you wanted it. I hope it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was created to display the periodic table, but it's a great piece of ui
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/
It does require a fair amount of jquery knowledge but, again, it's a great piece of ui a very adaptable.
That is, of course, if you're looking for something a bit more that a calendar.

**edit**
Since jquery is really not your thing here's what I think is a simple suggestion. 
On the controller side, load all training sessions ORDER ASC (I don't know how to work with Linq but surely it can be done). I'm also assuming that you know the BETWEEN dates of traings you're querying.
So in the controller you'd aglomerate the dates like this:

```
    public ActionResult Trainings()
    {
        //dummy data
        var trainings = new List<Training>();
        trainings.Add(new Training { TrainingDay = DateTime.Now });

        var week = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, List<Training>>() 
        { 
            { DayOfWeek.Monday, new List<Training>() },
            { DayOfWeek.Tuesday, new List<Training>() },
            { DayOfWeek.Wednesday, new List<Training>() },
            { DayOfWeek.Thursday, new List<Training>() },
            { DayOfWeek.Friday, new List<Training>() },
            { DayOfWeek.Saturday, new List<Training>() },
            { DayOfWeek.Sunday, new List<Training>() },
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < trainings.Count; i++) 
        {
            switch (trainings[i].TrainingDay.DayOfWeek)
            {
                case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                    week[DayOfWeek.Friday].Add(trainings[i]);
                    break;
                case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                    week[DayOfWeek.Monday].Add(trainings[i]);
                    break;
                case .....

            }
        }
        return View(week);
    }
```

this would get all the training's in the same day together (I've heard that some people go the gym more that once a day, not sure if that's true or not).
Now, you can have your view strongly type, so you change it to something like:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Dictionary<DayOfWeek, List<Training>>>" %>
```

and don't forget `<%@ Import %>` the Training `namespace` and finally you view could be something like this:

```
   <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Monday</td>
            <td>Tuesday</td>
            <td>Wednesday</td>
            <td>Thursday</td>
            <td>Friday</td>
            <td>Saturday</td>
            <td>Sunday</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <%foreach (KeyValuePair<DayOfWeek, List<Training>> entry in Model){%>
                <td>
                    <%if (entry.Key == DayOfWeek.Monday){
                       foreach (var training in entry.Value){
                        Response.Write(training.TrainingDay); 
                       } 
                    }%> 
                </td>
            <%} %>
        </tr>
   </table>
```

Obviously instead of repeating the same code for the entries you could create an extension method for the Html object.

Comment: jquery would only complicate things even more. I just would want to know how to properly show my data underneat the assiocated day.

Comment: I've edited my answer to work with tables instead of using jquery

Comment: i will try it out today, thank you very much - I believe I can use this.. Can't wait to  get home and try it out.